# Start/stop return code with Daemons Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, daemons

I've written some code that should run as a server and wrapped it with Daemons as `Daemons.run('myserver.rb')`. When I run it as `./daemon.rb start` it works but it is not informative at all, i.e. if `myserver.rb` throws an exception I will not even know my server did not start, Daemons will exit with exit code 0. Is there any way to tell Daemons to return a non-zero exit code if the wrapped script fails to start? Or perhaps another way for me to know if my server started successfully?

Comment: Could you check for the pid file?

Comment: Wondering same thing. This makes working with provisioning tools like Puppet very difficult as they rely on the exit codes to execute dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
d=Daemons.run('myserver.rb')
exit d.applications.length > 0 ? 0 : 1
```